# Is there a reason to not use "1" class with a small VSTO Add-in?

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio, excel, vsto

I know that in reality if you make a VSTO project in VS, that you start with several classes auto-generated before you write a line of code.  I also understand (I think) the single responsibility principle.

That said, I find myself writing several small VSTO projects (actual Add-in code is 60ish lines total) to be deployed on single machines.  They all work, and are mostly handing/transforming data that comes out of a robot or other machines so a human might make more sense of it.

Is there a reason I shouldn't be putting all my code into a single class?  I can easily keep track of something when it's this small (and clearly systematically named), and I feel like it's easier to maintain.

Right now I've done 4 where I forced myself to follow strict classes, and 2 just today where I threw all the code into one class.  I don't see a performance difference, and they seem to all work equally well with a fairly equal load.

Am I missing something?  I've never taking a programming class, so I'm sure I'm full of bad habits, but perhaps that's because I keep ending on things that seemingly work well?  I'd love to know if anyone has some examples, with more interest in VSTO in particular, of where this will go wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Project templates should recommend practices which work for most cases, both simple and complex. You can write both simple and complex projects with proper class hierarchy, but only simple projects can be effeciently written without following best practices.

That being said, you are not forced to follow any class hierarchy suggested by the project template. If using a single class works the best for you, you can use this approach. There is nothing wrong with choosing simple tools for simple problems. It is in fact a good idea if you make a conscious choice.

Preformance-wise, there will not be any considerable differences. It is about programming effeciency, not about execution effeciency.